# Extracting Strings on Multiline

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

### Extracting Strings on Multiline

Please share your ideas on this concern.
how do i extract the string **Domain/username** field on this multi threaded line.

Name        Username

COMP01-100  Domain\user.one

Name        Username

COMP02-100  Domain\test.user

Name        Username

COMP10-100  Domain\sample.user

--

**Note:** 
I should have searched for **COMP02-100** and extract **Domain\test.user** as result.

I think I should have used the php preg_match_all function but i just can't find the right syntax on this.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could get the desired result with these lines:

```
$search_string= 'COMP02-100';
preg_match("/$search_string (\w+\\\\\w+.\w+)/", $multiline, $matches);
```

`preg_match` is sufficient if you just want the first match

Comment: Efforts appreciated Mr. Beat..  You have just solved my problem.. :)